# Determine with reflection if a class property is an object that inherits List<T> or any type of collection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I need to use reflection to filter out all object properties that are collections. They are not always just generic lists, but a class that inherits a `List<T>` type. So as an example, I have a class `foo` with property of type `fooCollection`. `FooColection` looks like the following:

```
public class foo
{
    public FooCollection myCollection {get;set;}
}

public class fooCollection : List<Foo>
{
}
```

I do not know what to expect as the type of `List<T>`, but only need to know if it is a collection. How can I find this out? I asked a prior question, but worded it differently, and the results were not working with my particular instance.

I have tried examples such as the following, where I look through all properties of `foo`, and try to find the property that is `fooColelction`:

```
typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)
```

This is not working properly for me though. The type is not `IEnumerable`, though it is a collection. It inherits an `IEnumerable` type.

Here is an example of one of the Collection classes for a class object called `Policy`.

```
public class PolicyCollection : List<Policy>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This function takes a xml Policy collection and builds a PolicyCollection Class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xDocPolicyCollection">XML Document of an PolicyCollection</param>
    protected internal void LoadXml(XmlDocument xDocPolicyCollection)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode n in xDocPolicyCollection.GetElementsByTagName("Policy"))
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(n.OuterXml);

            Policy p = new Policy();
            p.LoadXml(xdoc);
            Add(p);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function takes a datatable of Policies collection and builds a PolicyCollection Class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dtContact">Data</param>
    protected internal void LoadDB(DataTable dtPolicyCollection)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtPolicyCollection.Rows)
        {
            Policy p = new Policy();
            p.LoadDB(dr);
            Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

This is different then a prior question because I am asking how to check this scenario for a property type that is a regular class, that Inherits `List<T>`, not a property that is `List<T>`.

Comment: Can you include the `FooCollection` class code?

Comment: Yes, one moment. I will put a general example to demonstrate. Now, instead of Foo, and fooCollection obviously this example is for Policy, and PolicyCollection.

Comment: @Yuval I don't thing `Type.IsGenericType` will work for OP's scenario where there's a type inheriting `List<T>`. Anyway OP, please create a [mcve].

Comment: It is not duplicate, as the answer was not correct for my situation. If the property was public List<Policy> then the question you are referencing would work, but it not.

Comment: Why do you need to know if the type is a list? This might be an XY problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @CodeCaster But checking agains't `IList` will work. I don't think OP needs the generic type parameter.

Comment: To only check if those properties are not null and init for unit test. If I iterate all. I wanted to use reflection, so that it was reusable, generic.

Comment: Like @Luaan said, that screams XY problem. You shouldn't inherit from `List<T>` in general, and you certainly should not have to resort to reflection in unit tests.

Comment: Would I maybe need to check base type of the property, then the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that a non-reified generic type (such as `IEnumerable<>`) can *never* be assigned anything. .NET generics simply don't work this way.

Instead, you could use something like this:

```
typeof(PolicyCollection)
.GetInterfaces()
.Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
```

`GetInterfaces` returns *all* the interfaces which are implemented by the given type, and then you simply check if there's anything that's an `IEnumerable<>`. By explicitly un-reifying the found generic interfaces, we can do a simple comparison with `IEnumerable<>` (or `IList<>` or whichever you prefer).

And of course, since `IEnumerable<>` also "requires" `IEnumerable`, you can simply check for that instead of the generic interface:

```
typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(PolicyCollection));
```

Comment: I tried this, and didn't work. See this is weird to me.  Why it is not recognizing that the property is a collection. I am using var prop in object.GetProperties() to check the class foo.  In that foreach, is where I am running your test against the prop. Instead of "typeof(PolicyCollction)" i am using "prop.GetType()" since it is unknown at that time what T is for List<T>.

Comment: @Casey: You need to use the [`PropertyInfo.PropertyType` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not `.GetType()`. `PropertyType` will get you the declared type of the property, whereas `GetType()` will get you the type of `prop` (which is `PropertyInfo`)

Comment: No way, I am so sorry, and thank you so much. This helped me learn more about reflection going through this. That was the problem. Thanks again!